# arm neon transpose 4x4 uint32

Tags: c++, image-processing, arm, neon

I'm trying to rotate and image counter-clockwise by 90 degrees, and then flip it horizontally.

My first approach, was to just use OpenCV:

```
cv::transpose(in, tmp); // transpose around top left
cv::flip(tmp, out, -1); // flip on both axes
```

For performance, I'm trying to merge the two functions into one.

My code:

```
void ccw90_hflip_640x480(const cv::Mat& img, cv::Mat& out)
{
    assert(img.cols == 640 && img.rows == 480);
    assert(out.cols == 480 && out.cols == 640);

    uint32_t* imgData = (uint32_t*)img.data;
    uint32_t* outData = (uint32_t*)out.data;

    uint32_t *pRow = imgData;
    uint32_t *pEnd = imgData + (640 * 480);
    uint32_t *dstCol = outData + (480 * 640) - 1;

    for( ; pRow != pEnd; pRow += 640, dstCol -= 1)
    {
        for(uint32_t *ptr = pRow, *end = pRow + 640, *dst = dstCol;
            ptr != end;
            ++ptr, dst -= 480)
        {
            *dst = *ptr;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought the above would be faster, but it's not. I can't think of any reason it wouldn't be faster, beside OpenCV possibly using NEON.

I found this article/presentation:
http://shervinemami.info/NEON_RotateBGRX.swf

The transposition and flipping are blurred together in a way that makes it very hard to modify to where it would rotate the other way, and flip around the horizontal axis like I need it too. The article is very old, so I'm hoping there is a more straightforward way of doing what I need.

So what's the easiest way to transpose a 4x4 matrix of uint32 using arm NEON?

Comment: _"For performance"_? How have you determined that this effort will produce a more performant program?

Comment: Indeed, I've traveled to the future, where I confirmed that my arm neon implementation is faster. Unfortunately, before I could write down the algorithm, my time machine malfunctioned, sending me to an alternate universe, where everyone uses linked lists instead of vectors.

Comment: See [here](https://community.arm.com/thread/3002) for solutions (scroll down a bit for code that actually works).

Comment: @PaulR Thanks for the link. I've got transposition working as per the article, but it'll take some time to get the full algorithm pieced together and do some measurements.

Comment: @PaulR I ended up using the first method from the article you recommended(vtrn, vtrn, vswp, vswp). The de-interleave loading discussed there was a no-go because of the element size/count I'm working with. After updating the above algorithm to process 4x4 pixels at a time using the aforementioned transposition instructions(and flipping, as discussed in the *.swf file linked above), I was able to decrease the run time to ~30% of what it was. This makes your response the most correct, so if you post an answer, I will accept. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to know it worked out - feel free to write this up as a self-answer for the benefit of future readers (I'm on a mobile device just now so not in a great position to write up a decent answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is equivalent to the OpenCV calls in the original post, but performs several times faster(at least on my device).

Using Neon did indeed increase performance significantly. Since the transposition happens inside the CPU, memory access can be streamlined to read and write pixels in sets of four, instead of one at a time, as discussed in the comments.

```
void ccw90_hflip_640x480_neon(const cv::Mat& img, cv::Mat& out)
{
    assert(img.cols == 640 && img.rows == 480);
    assert(out.cols == 480 && out.cols == 640);

    uint32_t *pRow = (uint32_t*)img.data;
    uint32_t *pEnd = (uint32_t*)img.data + (640 * 480);
    uint32_t *dstCol = (uint32_t*)out.data + (480 * 640) - (480 * 3) - 4;

    for( ; pRow != pEnd; pRow += 640 * 4, dstCol -= 4)
    {
        for(uint32_t *ptr = pRow, *end = pRow + 640, *dst = dstCol;
            ptr != end;
            ptr += 4, dst -= 480 * 4)
        {
            uint32_t* in0 = ptr;
            uint32_t* in1 = in0 + 640;
            uint32_t* in2 = in1 + 640;
            uint32_t* in3 = in2 + 640;

            uint32_t* out0 = dst;
            uint32_t* out1 = out0 + 480;
            uint32_t* out2 = out1 + 480;
            uint32_t* out3 = out2 + 480;

            asm("vld1.32 {d0, d1}, [%[in0]]    \n"
                "vld1.32 {d2, d3}, [%[in1]]    \n"
                "vld1.32 {d4, d5}, [%[in2]]    \n"
                "vld1.32 {d6, d7}, [%[in3]]    \n"
                "vtrn.32 q0, q1                \n"
                "vtrn.32 q2, q3                \n"
                "vswp d1, d4                   \n"
                "vswp d3, d6                   \n"
                "vrev64.32 q0, q0              \n"
                "vrev64.32 q1, q1              \n"
                "vrev64.32 q2, q2              \n"
                "vrev64.32 q3, q3              \n"
                "vswp d0, d1                   \n"
                "vswp d2, d3                   \n"
                "vswp d4, d5                   \n"
                "vswp d6, d7                   \n"
                "vst1.32 {d6, d7}, [%[out0]]   \n"
                "vst1.32 {d4, d5}, [%[out1]]   \n"
                "vst1.32 {d2, d3}, [%[out2]]   \n"
                "vst1.32 {d0, d1}, [%[out3]]   \n"
                :
                : [out0] "r" (out0), [out1] "r" (out1), [out2] "r" (out2), [out3] "r" (out3),
                    [in0] "r" (in0), [in1] "r" (in1), [in2] "r" (in2), [in3] "r" (in3)
                : "d0", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7"
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to compile this function on gcc compiler. I get the error - "Error: unknown mnemonic `vld1.32' -- `vld1.32 {d0,d1},[x4]'"

Comment: Have you enabled neon instruction set? and is your target arch 32bit? arm64 uses a different instruction set.

Comment: I have arm64 processor. Can you share a link where I can find examples for the instruction set for arm64.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a straight 1:1 translation. There are other small differences beside the names of the instructions. You'll have to read up and learn the basics of arm64. If you don't want to do that, you could always try intrinsics (which produce both 32 and 64 bit assembly automatically) and see if you get enough speed with that.

Comment: You're missing a `"memory"` clobber, or dummy `"m"` and `"=m"` operands to tell the compiler which memory is read or written.  [How can I indicate that the memory \*pointed\* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56432259)

Answer (score 0):

Neon will not help significantly<sup>Note</sup>. Your code is simply moving data; neon can not make the underlying memory faster by a significant amount. See [this article](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka13544.html); using the PLD will also help. I would suggest that you process `dst` in order and jump around with `ptr`. The cache will pre-fill `ptr` and `dst` will line fill.

Here is an alternate form of traversing memory (variable names may not make sense),

```
uint32_t *pEnd = imgData + 640;
uint32_t *dstCol = outData;

for( ; pRow != pEnd; pRow ++)
{
    for(uint32_t *ptr = pRow, *dst = dstCol, *end = dst + 480;
        dst != end;
        ptr += 640, dst++)
    {
        *dst = *ptr;
    }
    // could flush `dstCol` here as it is complete or hope the system clues in.
    dstCol += 480;
}
```

The idea is to fill `dst` in order and jump around accessing the `imgData`.  All modern memory will fill more efficiently if you write it out in order.  The cache and synchronous DRAM usually fill several 32 bit words at a time.  We can unroll the inner loop with knowledge of the L1 cache.  It is either 32 or 64 bytes representing 8 or 16 32bit pixels.  The fill will be a similar amount, so you could reduce the transpose to *cacheable* blocks and process each at one time. Think of the the 640x480 image as being composes of 8*8 pixel tiles (minimum L1 cache size) and process each in turn.

After you do this, the NEON instructions may gain some percentage.  However, optimizing the load/store unit (common to all CPU units) should be the first step.

**NOTE**: Neon is SIMD (single instruction, multiple data) and it excels at number crunching the pixels to give a computational boost by processing several at a time.  It does have some instructions that will optimize memory traversal, but the underlying memory is the same for the CORE CPU units and the SIMD/NEON units.  It is possible NEON will give a boost but I think it is futile until you have optimized your access order for your memory system.

Comment: What I am saying will be more apparent with larger images and less so if you are only processing small blocks.  Note that [Paul R](http://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r)s [NEON link](https://community.arm.com/thread/3002) has great info by Peter Harris for processing a 16x16 tile using NEON.  Put this together with the information above and you will probably have a near optimal routine.

Comment: Hmm, that initial reasoning seems in general counterintuitive to me - the store buffers, L1 and L2 will always absorb some of the overhead of stores, whereas if the load misses at L1 you've got nothing to do but wait. Allowing the store buffers to merge writes more efficiently at the cost of virtually guaranteeing every load to miss at L1 (in the absence of very careful prefetching) doesn't seem like it'd be much of a win, but I'll admit it's not something I've actually benchmarked (and obviously depends a lot on system-specific factors).

Comment: @Notlikethat Yes, the store buffers will work with sequential writes and are of limited size.  L1 will miss on initial reads, but it as 4way by at least 32k.  The stride is only 480 entries so the 2nd column read will be in the cache.  However, I recommend the OP try it.  A definitive answer can only be found by measuring.  For certain the tiling approach will be better.  It depends on the whole memory system, but I am pretty sure on a large class of CPUs the original algorithm is doing more physical writes; whereas the 2nd will probably have the same reads.

Comment: @artlessnoise This is interesting. I didn't know that writing was also subject to cache performance, which is why I coded for ordered reads. I'm still going to try the neon optimizations as well, in hopes that both reads and writes will experience some cache benefit.

Comment: As noted in the comments below the main post, processing 4x4 pixels at a time using neon resulted in a massive performance gain. Once I had modified my original algorithm with neon, I also tested a second version optimized for sequential writes instead of sequential reads as you suggested. The performance was similar, but appeared to be ~25% slower using sequential writes. I also read a bit about PLD as well, and it seems like it could further improve performance, but the performance improvement I've already achieved will get us by for now. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the 4x4 pixels at a time will achieve what I meant by the write re-order.  You have a 32bit pixel so you will be writing at least 4*4byte.  This maybe the size of SDRAM lines; the main thing is to write a line at a time.  So, after doing the tiling I wouldn't expect a gain.  Or did you mean versus your 25% slower than the original code?  It is possible that the cache was buffering the 32bit writes so that only a single line was written in the orignal case.